# VBA - copy button in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Button that copies content control (Plain Text Context Control & Combo Box Content Controls) to clipboard in Microsoft Word. I understand that I need to highlight each one first, but due to using a loop, it does one item at a content control box at a time and ends on the last one selected only. I need the 'section' and the 'N/A' content control boxs to be selected and copied to the clipboard. [Click here to view document](https://ibb.co/ZxL9hZs)

Here is the code the loops through them all, but ends on the last one. Have a little coding background, but new to VBA so any help would be appreciated!

```
Dim cc As ContentControl
Private Sub ToggleButton2_Click()
    For Each cc In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
        While cc.Range.Text <> ""
        cc.Range.Select
        Wend
    Next cc
End Sub
```

Comment: You understand wrong. There is no need or benefit from selecting anything. You can go straight ahead and copy the object or from the object:- `cc.Range.Copy` or perhaps `cc.Range.Text.Copy`.

Comment: No, you don't have to select (highlight) anything. What is the purpose of copying them to the clipboard? In any event, you will find that cc.Range.Text <> "" will always be true. Of greater significant, though, is that the While ... Wend loop you have there simply means the first content control will be selected over and over in an endless loop.